# Using executors and synchronizing CountDownLatch in different classes

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi guys I was following a tutorial and I am curious about a few things that I tried applying my knowledge acquired from tutorial.

The below is a Runner class

```
package Tutorial2;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Runner {

    public void runIt() {

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch (6);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Process(i, latch));
        }

        ExecutorService executor2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        for (int i = 1000; i < 1010; i++) {
            executor2.submit(new Process(i, latch));
        }

        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Program Ended");
   }
}
```

Then below is my Processor class

```
package Tutorial2;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Process implements Runnable {

    private int id;
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(6);

    public Process(int id, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.id = id;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Task Starting ID : " + id);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Task Finished ID : " + id);
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

It's pretty simple what I am trying to do. So there are a few questions that I wanna ask you professionals. So I understand that CountDownLatch counts down by one whenever .countDown is called. Then .await will return if the countdown is zero.

What I am curious about is that the CountDownLatch in Runner class and CountDownLatch in Process class should be different but reaching zero in CountDownLatch of Process class also seems to trigger .await which I put in Runner class. How does this work when I am only passing CountDownLatch as a parameter into Process class and no value of CountDownLatch from Process class is returned back to Runner class?

Also, below, I set up two Executors so that each executor will countdown the CountDownLatch but I seem to be getting more number of threads being processed than the number I input (6) before it is returned. What am I doing wrong? How would I make it so that "Program Ended" is printed when CountDownLatch reaches 0 i.e. threads have been run 6 times in total from both the executors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `this.latch = latch;` you overwrite object's reference with the one which passed in the constructor argument (i.e. the one which created in the `runIt` method). The assignment `CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(6);` in `Process` class is useless, it does nothing. Just confuses you.

Second question is unclear... Yes, as soon it counted down to zero, it releases `await`... Not sure how it is related to how much threads/executors you have.

Comment: So the CountDownLatch in the Runner class is still being used within Process class? because I thought if a value is passed in the parameter to another class, it only overrides the 'value' but still uses the variable in the same class in its methods.

Comment: Yea don't worry about the second one I realized that if I set latch to be static then it works

Comment: @forJ Java variables only keep references to objects. You create object in two places in `runIt` and in the Process class, but you overwrite reference to latter with former. Words "overrides the 'value'" make no sense in Java

Comment: Hey so based on what you said I have tried something else. I made int countDown in one class and made same int countDown in another class. In one class, I made a constructor to pass countDown from another class which I made this.countDown = countDown to make sure they refer to same variables. Then I decreased the number until 0 in the class where countDown was received in constructor. Then in another class I made it print countDown but the countDown from two classes do not point to the same value.

Comment: So simply put I pointed countDown of one class to countDown of another class and in the class that received countDown reference, I decreased the value till 0 and called for countDown value in the other class but the countDown values are different in two classes which conflicts what you said? that Java only saves reference to the object

Comment: @forJ, there is no CountDownLatch _in_ the runner class.  There is no CountDownLatch _in_ the Process class.  There is a _local variable_ named `latch` in the `runIt()` method, and there is a _field_ (a.k.a., _member variable_) named `latch` in each instance of the Process class, and the local variable and all of those fields _refer to_ the same `Process` instance which is located _in_ the Java heap.

Comment: @james large  ohhh so if you have local variable in method everything that it refers to while the method is running all refer to the same latch??

Answer (score 2):

> I made `int countDown` in one class and made same `int countDown` in another class. In one class, I made a constructor to pass `countDown` from another class which I made `this.countDown = countDown` to make sure they refer to same variables. Then I ... but the countDown from two classes do not point to the same value.

A variable is not a thing that anything else in Java can "refer to."  A variable is a named location that can hold a *value*.

All values in Java fall into either one of two categories; *Object references*, and *primitive values*.  An Object reference is a pointer to an object on the Java heap.  A primitive value basically is just a number, like `5`.  `5` is a primitive value of type `int`.

---

When your program executes `this.countDown = countDown`, That does not establish any relationship between the two variables.  All it does is set `this.countDown` equal to whatever value happened to be in `countDown` at that particular moment in time.  If the program subsequently changes either `this.countDown` or `countDown`, that has no effect on the other variable.

In some programming languages, you can create an *alias*---a thing that looks like a unique variable, but which actually is a reference to some *other* variable---but you can never do that in Java.

Comment: Ok that really helps with my understanding. So it did not change with the primitive value because they were just pointing at numbers but in case of latch above its pointing to object so its changing everytime its reference is changed?

Comment: @forJ, Yes.  A variable of type `CountDownLatch` holds a reference to an object on the heap.  Two different `CountDownLatch` variables can both refer to the same object.  Changing one of the variables (e.g., to refer to a _different_ `CountDownLatch` instance) would not affect the other, but that's not what your code was doing.  Your code was using the common shared instance to communicate between the threads.  When you changed the type of the variables to `int`, then there can be no shared instance because an `int` value is not an object on the heap.

Comment: So even if I was referencing an object, if I had latch out of the method, encompassed in the class as a whole, the value of latch would not have changed? It only did because its a local variable in the method?